# Date and GregorianCalendar millisecond handling

Tags: java, android, date

I'm a little confused of the handling between the java Date Class and GregorianCalendar in Android (2.1).
In this example, the year, month, day, hour, minute values are coming from Date and Time pickers.

```
Date date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
GregorianCalendar senddate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);

Log.v(LOG_TAG, senddate.getTimeInMillis() + "");
Log.v(LOG_TAG, date.getTime() + "");
```

output from the logging:

```
1297604340000
61255744740000
```

why is the date object so far off. what did i miss?

**edit:**

I ran my sample code again.

> 1297609440000
>   61255749840000
>   2011 - 1 - 13 - 16 - 4 (year - month - dayofmonth - hour - minute)

getting the values from:

```
int month = dpDate.getMonth();
int day = dpDate.getDayOfMonth();
int year = dpDate.getYear();

int hour = dpTime.getCurrentHour();
int minute = dpTime.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: Can you please show the values of your year, month... variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the cause is the difference in the construction API, to be precise, the `year` field. For `Date` class the `year` field is the year minus 1900, where as for `GregorianCalendar` it's the actual year.

Comment: Argh! That would make sense. Checking the API and re-doing the function proved it right. Thanks

Comment: No probs. Watch out for `month` too, it's 0-based. I've had some nasty bugs related to that one in the past((